# Is there a way to disable the weather icon in Skype?

Tags: skype, skype-for-linux

I just had an update for Skype on Linux Mint, after which this icon started showing up whenever I open Skype:

[image: A screenshot of the upper right corner of Skype. The three-dotted menu button can be seen, along with a sun which says the current temperature is 23°C.]

My guess is it's telling me the current weather of where I am located based on my IP address. I guess it's a nice feature, but it's kind of distracting to have a yellow/orange looking orb in the middle of a completely dark window (the theme I am using for Skype).

Is there a way to disable that thing? I tried looking in the settings of Skype, but for now I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Hello. Downgrade if it's a big problem that you can't simply ignore. I honestly doubt there would be a setting to disable a random UI element, no easy way otherwise.

Comment: It's a freaking voice call app. Why would anybody thought it's a good idea to put a weather in the center of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype recently added an option within the settings to disable it, as defined in their [support page](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34951/what-is-the-today-tab-in-skype-and-how-do-i-use-it). To disable the weather icon:

1. Click on your profile picture (in the upper left).
2. Choose the **Settings** button, with a ⚙️ gear icon. This will open the settings window.

Alternatively, you can open the Settings by clicking on Tools > Settings in the upper menu, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Comma</kbd>

3. Click on the **Appearance** button, with a  magic wand icon.
4. Scroll down and you should have an option to disable the weather icon, as well as the Today tab:

[image: A screenshot of the Skype settings window, opened on the Appearance tab, with the options to disable the weather icon and the Today tab circled with a red hand drawn circle.]

Comment: The linked Skype help doesn't actually say how to disable the weather icon, but it's what made me realise they actually added it as an option (the last time I checked, that wasn't an option yet).

Comment: And the same place even allows to disable the useless “Skype Today” as well, great!